# preg_match_all no results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
    preg_match_all('|<tr>(.*?)</tr>|', '<table>
<tr>
<td>oo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ddd</td>
</tr>
</table>', $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

why this doesn't show any results.
I want to get second match $matches[1][2]

Comment: Advice: don't use regex to parse HTML. Use a genuine HTML parser instead.

Comment: I second this advice, however what do you mean by Genuine HTML parser? Any good way to do that in PHP?

Comment: I see you only have one group, `(.*?)`. What do you expect to find in `$matches[1][2]`?

Comment: @AlexanderMP http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Note: matches counting starts from 0. So, if you need second match, you would use $matches[1][1].

Comment: Do not use simplehtmldom if you can avoid it: there are way faster methods: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php/3577662#3577662

Comment: simplehtmldom use same codes as regex and preg_match I dont see any difference with my code below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the **s** pattern modifier

`preg_match_all('|<tr>(.*?)</tr>|s', ...`